# How could I make Parity connect with my local Ethereum blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity

When I run ./parity under /target/release it automatically connects to the public Ethereum blockchain. (It starts syncing with the actual Ethereum blockchain of 900,000 blocks.)

I want to connect into my local Ethereum blockchain that I have created.

[Q] How could I make Parity connect with my local Ethereum blockchain?

I have an ongoing local Ethereum blockchain.

I am running my server as:

```
geth --rpc --datadir "/Users/avatar/Library/MyEthereumEbloc" --dev --unlock 0  
--minerthreads 1 --targetgaslimit "994712388" 
--ipcpath "/Users/avatar/Library/MyEthereumEbloc/geth.ipc"  --bootnodes 
enode://8cc3166d6e3ca794d95a00ba7d42127bffe5cd08a89d08ff6adfd
2f552b7309702110ee3f10996cdeca0b792922e1cc257
c4f9f6fd62eb2c2987231e39e5761f@78.120.155.145:3000  
--port 3000 --networkid "23444" console
```

I am running my client as:

```
geth --datadir "/Users/avatar/Library/MyEthereumEbloc" 
--dev attach ipc:/Users/avatar/Library/MyEthereumEbloc/geth.ipc
```

Thank you for your valuable help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two methods are possible:

1. **Import/ Export**

> On 1.2 and above, use Geth's export feature along with Parity's import:
>
> mkfifo /tmp/chain.rlp && geth export /tmp/chain.rlp & sleep 1 && parity import /tmp/chain.rlp

2. **Syncing**

Basically you would have to run a geth node with your private chain and fire up a parity node that connects to your network and syncs it.
Since Parity 1.3 there is a feature called *SnapSync*, but I doubt it can be used with geth.

Further details:|
https://github.com/ethcore/parity/wiki/Importing%20a%20chain%20from%20Geth

Comment: I have done the method 1 as you suggested. Exported blockchain to /tmp/avatar.rlp ||| I got the following error  when I run  ($ ./parity import /tmp/avatar.rlp)  ERROR: Configured for Frontier/Homestead using Ethash engine Cannot import block: Block(UnknownParent(0000000000000000000000000000000000000000‌​00000000000000000000‌​0000))

Comment: Looks like the genesis block, maybe you have to config it manually, that is migrate your genesis configuration to parity...