# Adding private network peers to Parity

Tags: private-blockchain, parity

If possible, I would like to use [parity](https://github.com/ethcore/parity) with my private ethereum network.

This answer (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/9148/4575) provides us a solution that `geth` will run on the background and `parity` will pull information from `geth`.

[Q] Is it possible to run only `parity` (`geth` won't run on the background) that is connect to the private etheum network and do mining, deploy contract, send transactions etc.?

If yes is there any well explained tutorial related to adding private network peers to Parity and make Parity to connect into the private network's chain instead of the public ethereum's chain.

Is this link might help me?https://github.com/ethcore/parity/wiki/Configuring-Parity. If yes which parameters should I focus on to change? 
Also how could I add `admin.addPeer("enode://<id>@<ip>:<port>?discport=0");` and provide the `--networkid` to `Parity` to allow it to connect into the private network like we could do in `geth`?

Example by using `geth` as follows I can connect into my private network:

```
id="<enodeId>";
datapath="/MyEthereumEbloc"
geth --networkid 23422 --datadir="$datapath" --rpccorsdomain '*' --rpc --rpcaddr "localhost" --rpccorsdomain="*" --rpcport="8545"--bootnodes enode://$id@<ip>:<port>
```

Please note that I was not able to find any tutorial related make `parity` connect into private ethereum network, which might be very helpful.

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if I get your question correctly. Assuming you have a private network running with 5 clients on network ID `13337` and `myGenesis.json` chain configuration.

- `enode://0000..0001@192.168.178.101:36541`
- `enode://0000..0002@192.168.178.102:36542`
- `enode://0000..0003@192.168.178.103:36543`
- `enode://0000..0004@192.168.178.104:36544`
- `enode://0000..0005@192.168.178.105:36545`

Add these nodes to a file, let's say `myPrivateNetwork.txt`, one entry per line:

```
enode://0000..0001@192.168.178.101:36541
enode://0000..0002@192.168.178.102:36542
enode://0000..0003@192.168.178.103:36543
enode://0000..0004@192.168.178.104:36544
enode://0000..0005@192.168.178.105:36545
```

And subsequently, run Parity with `--chain myGenesis.json --network-id 13337 --reserved-peers myPrivateNetwork.txt --reserved-only`. Or add it to the config file:

```
[parity]
chain = "myGenesis.json"

[network]
id = 13337
reserved_only = true
reserved_peers = "./myPrivateNetwork.txt"
```

This will establish a private network containing only your nodes:

```
--reserved-peers FILE        Provide a file containing enodes, one per line.
                             These nodes will always have a reserved slot on top
                             of the normal maximum peers. (default: None)
--reserved-only              Connect only to reserved nodes. (default: false)
```

Adding reserved peers also works from the Web3 console by issuing:

```
api.parity.addReservedPeer('enode://0000..0007@192.168.178.107:36547')
```

Note, that you have to enable the `parity` json rpc api.

You can also run a [private development chain](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/wiki/Private-development-chain) with `parity --chain dev`.

Comment: Thank you @5chdn I am sorry if my question is not clear. enodes does not have to be reserved, any peer can connect to the private network. I was trying to explain that: I know the `--network-id` and `enode://<id>@<ip>:<port>?discport=0` of the node that will allow me to connect into the private network. By using `geth` I am able to connect into it. So I was wondering by using same information and chain-data created by `geth`, could `parity` connect into the private network?

Comment: Sure, just see my answer and set `reserved_only` to `false`.

Comment: Is `myGenesis.json` file same as `CustomGenesis.json` that used under `geth init CustomGenesis.json`? for example: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/378fb95285c91d40bf6f1b9f4bf2acd2@5chdn

Comment: No, Parity uses a slightly different format, but there is a tool to convert geth genesis to parity genesis. Somewhere.

Comment: ^ https://github.com/keorn/parity-spec

Comment: @5chdn How could I open Web3 console to add my peer?, `geth` console was working but in `parity`, `parity console` does not exist

Comment: @5chdn, I did all your guidance but I was not able to connect to my private chain :(. The way I run parity: `parity --chain parity.json --network-id 23422 --bootnodes enode://<enode-id>@<IP>:<port#>` It gives following output `2017-03-17 15:56:19      0/ 0/25 peers      5 KiB db    7 KiB chain    2 KiB queue    4 KiB sync` but nothing happens.

Comment: Parity Console: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13196 / It's better to use reserved peers rather than bootnodes.

Comment: @5chdn sorry to keep bothering you.  `parity --chain parity.json --network-id 23422  --reserved-peers myPrivateNetwork.txt` seems didn't work as well on my case :( When I use geth I can add the peer as `admin.addPeer("enode://enode@IP:port?discport=0");`, but parity also does not accept `?discport=0` inside myPricateNetwork.txt.

Comment: You maybe should get on Gitter and we can sort this out :)

Answer (score 4):

To add a reserved peer via JSONRPC API, you can do this with:

```
curl --data '{"method":"parity_addReservedPeer","params":["enode://a979fb575495b8d6db44f750317d0f4622bf4c2aa3365d6af7c284339968eef29b69ad0dce72a4d8db5ebb4968de0e3bec910127f134779fbcb0cb6d3331163c@22.99.55.44:7770"],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8545
```

Make sure you have `parity_set` JSONRPC API enabled.

You can also call it directly from the Parity console with:

```
api.parity.addReservedPeer("enode://a979fb575495b8d6db44f750317d0f4622bf4c2aa3365d6af7c284339968eef29b69ad0dce72a4d8db5ebb4968de0e3bec910127f134779fbcb0cb6d3331163c@22.99.55.44:7770")
```

For this, ensure you have `parity_set` DApps API enabled.