# How to open the JavaScript console on Parity?

Tags: parity, javascript, console, parity-wallet

There is nothing like `parity console`.

How to open the JavaScript console on Parity?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Either use the `geth console` attached to parity or use the Parity UI application *Parity/Web3 Console*.

To attach Geth console to Parity, (on Linux) use:

```
geth attach ~/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/jsonrpc.ipc
```

On MacOS use:

```
geth attach ~/Library/Application Support/io.parity.ethereum/jsonrpc.ipc
```

To access the Parity/Web3 Console, open the UI, go to Applications and open the *Parity/Web3 Console*:

[image: Parity Console]

Comment: folder `~/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum` does not seem to exist on my case. I guess because I tried it on mac. Also Inside `geth` it says `'api' is not defined.` @5chdn

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: Under `~/Library/Application Support/io.parity.ethereum/` folder, `jsonrpc.ipc` does not show up. Could it be`/Users/avatar/Library/Application Support/io.parity.ethereum/ipc/parity-chain.ipc` ? @5chdn.

Comment: Jesus, all the platforms, I don't have a mac for testing right now. Did you find _any_ ipc?

Comment: Yes I did find the ipc but it refuse connection :) `[~]$ sudo geth attach /Users/alper/Library/Application\ Support/io.parity.ethereum/ipc/parity-chain.ipc` gives an error as =  `Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: dial unix /Users/alper/Library/Application Support/io.parity.ethereum/ipc/parity-chain.ipc: connect: connection refused` @5chdn

Answer (score 7):

A [Node.js CLI Console](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Basic-Usage#nodejs-cli-console) can be used per the Parity wiki:

You can install [node/NPM](http://nodejs.org) and use its console. Once you have node/NPM installed, you'll just need to install the latest web3 module:

```
$ npm install web3
```

From then on you just need to run `node` and require the web3 module:

```
$ node
> Web3 = require("web3")
> web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
```

After this point, you'll be able to use the web3 API from with this environment, e.g.:

```
> web3.eth.blockNumber
743397
```

Comment: Could I run following command `api.parity.addReservedPeer('enode://0000..0007@<IP>:<Port#>')` under node? Since I was not able to run it, parity could not connect to my private network and `web.eth.blockNumber` returns 0. @eth

Comment: @Avatar: `api.parity` isn't part of `web3`.  Maybe ask a separate question and someone can answer.

Answer (score 5):

To open the Parity console, use geth.

```
geth attach http://localhost:8545
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @eth's response; if you like to have Parity's api calls; just install parity's api package instead of web3.

```
$ npm install @parity/api
$ node
```

On node console :

```
>// import the actual Api class
>const Api = require("@parity/api");

>// do the setup
>const provider = new Api.Provider.Http('http://localhost:8545');
>const api = new Api(provider);

// use api.parity.addReservedPeer
api.parity.addReservedPeer("enode://d64d5f74b1715c525dc88e87a52eca1574c09593ed29401d205ecfef9fbfe52fa308f966bab3a5966da1bb74212fecdb328cddceb572c38b536c597166784347@203080240034.static.ctinets.com:35423").then((data)=> {console.log(data)})
```