# JavaScript console on Parity: unable to unlock account. Error: Method not found

Tags: parity, console

[How to open the JavaScript console on Parity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/13197/4575) guide us to open a console for communicate with `Parity`.

Inside the console I was not able to unlock my `eth.account` using `personal.unlockAccount()`. I faced with following error: `Method not found`.

```
personal.unlockAccount("0x75a4c787c5c18c587b284a904165ff06a269b48c")
Unlock account 0x75a4c787c5c18c587b284a904165ff06a269b48c
Passphrase:
Error: Method not found
```

**[Q]** How could I prevent this error from error happening in order to unlock my `eth.account` successfully?

How I run Parity:

```
parity --chain parity.json --network-id 32344 --reserved-peers myPrivateNetwork.txt --jsonrpc-apis web3,eth,net,parity,parity_accounts,traces,rpc,parity_set,personal -ludp=debug,tcp=debug,sync=debug --author "0x75a4c787c5c18c587b284a904165ff06a269b48d"
```

Please note that java console sees personal.

```
> personal.  //press tab
personal._requestManager personal.constructor personal.getListAccounts personal.listAccounts personal.lockAccount personal.newAccount personal.sendTransaction personal.sign personal.unlockAccount
```

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Comment: What's the output of eth.accounts?

Comment: `["0x00941611ff247dc876d11cd0629b79d818814eb1"]` so I guess should I import the private key of the address I want to unlock? if yes, do you know the way? @5chdn

Comment: You can't unlock an account without private key. If you have another question, please let's not add them to the comments here.

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/16033/4575 @5chdn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Method not found` message is ambiguous / misleading. It basically says, something is wrong. Often the most obvious reasons are:

1. Mistyped command (happens, unlikely if you use tab-completion).
2. Unavailable APIs (i.e., you haven't enabled the personal JSONRPC API).
3. The called method fails for some reason (i.e., there is no account available for unlocking).

Comment: I import my account by using parity gui, on console I see the account I want to un-lock on eth.accounts. but still personal.unlock gives the same error. > `eth.accounts[3]
"0x75a4c787c5c18c587b284a904165ff06a269b48c"
> personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[3])
Unlock account 0x75a4c787c5c18c587b284a904165ff06a269b48c
Passphrase:
Error: Method not found`@5chdn♦

Comment: Wrong passphrase :)

Comment: Passphrase I am using unlock the account on the parity gui :( @5chdn♦

Comment: Restart your client with --geth flag or use personal_sendTransaction instead.

Answer (score 11):

You need to run parity with the appropriate API enabled. The API is the `personal` API.

For example:

`parity --chain ropsten --warp --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,personal,parity"`

Comment: I am running with following parameters(`--jsonrpc-apis web3,eth,net,parity,parity_accounts,traces,rpc,parity_set,personal`) but still giving the same error. Java console sees personal interface.@Thomas Clowes

Comment: I added on my question how I run parity. @Thomas Clowes

Comment: There is no personal rpcapi. The command above works for me and geth console allows me to unlock the account. Which version are you using.

Comment: `Parity: version Parity/v1.7.0-unstable-1dddbf3-20170317/x86_64-macos/rustc1.15.1` @5chdn

Comment: I can't even create a new account: `> personal.newAccount("avatar")
Error: Method not found` @Thomas Clowes

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue of "Error: Method not found" and found solution :

example :

parity  --chain ropsten --rpccorsdomain http://127.0.0.1:8180 --jsonrpc-apis "web3,eth,personal,pubsub,net,parity,parity_pubsub,traces,rpc,secretstore" --ipc-apis "web3,eth,personal,pubsub,net,parity,parity_pubsub,parity_accounts,traces,rpc,secretstore"  --author "0x007afe2ff60fee864e700ece6ddad0be5303f188"  --stratum

I put parameters of --jsonrpc-apis and --ipc-apis  as above.

See https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Configuring-Parity  for details.