# JavaScript console on Parity: How could I import account's private key, which I would like to unlock?

Tags: parity, private-key

In native `geth` applicaton, I was able to unlock accounts with only account address and its passphrase.

[How to open the JavaScript console on Parity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/16010/4575) guide us to open a console for communicate with `Parity`.

When I use JavaScript console on Parity, I was not able to do the same. Please see following [JavaScript console on Parity: unable to unlock account. Error: Method not found](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/16010/4575).

I have told that:

> You can't unlock an account without private key.

Based on that; using JavaScript console on Parity: How could I import account's private key(which was created using `geth`), which I would like to unlock?

Comment: Why do you want to do it via console? Try `parity account import <file>`.

Comment: I keep facing with following error: `Importing accounts failed.` I tried to import file that is stored under keystore that is created by geth. @5chdn

Comment: I import the account from parity gui, but when I try to unlock in on the javascript console, personal does not unlock in. @5chdn

Comment: Is it visible when you type `eth.accounts` ?

Comment: Yes sir. it returns the account which I imported via parity's browser. @5chdn♦

Comment: I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: Does it work on your java console? @5chdn

Comment: With following parameters the account is able to unlock: `--unlock "0x75a4c787c5c18c587b284a904165ff06a269b49d" --password password.txt` but I can't do it on the console, I am not sure what is wrong. @5chdn

Comment: I can't even create a new account: `> personal.newAccount("avatar")
Error: Method not found` @5chdn

Comment: Are you using `geth attach` or the built-in parity console dapp? If the latter is the case, you need to additionally enable the `--dapps-apis` too. Note this feature will be merged with `--jsonrpc-apis` in 1.7.

Comment: geth attach: `geth attach /Users/alper/Library/Application\ Support/io.parity.ethereum/jsonrpc.ipc console` @5chdn

Comment: We are running in circles. Your answer is [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15935/javascript-console-on-parity-unable-to-unlock-account-error-method-not-found/16010#16010). You don't need to import your account if it's already visible by `eth.accounts`. Wrong password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import an account from geth, type on your terminal:

```
parity wallet import ~/.ethereum/keystore/UTC--2015-10-15T18-13-54.xxxxxx --password ~/path/to/password.txt
```