# Unable to unlock account with Parity and Web3 on the testnet

Tags: parity, web3.py, debian

I'm running a local Parity node for the testnet (Ropsten) on Debian (Jessie). I'm using web3.py to connect to this node and create transactions.

I've created a new account:

```
parity account new --chain ropsten
```

I'm running my parity node with the following options

```
/usr/bin/parity --chain ropsten --no-ui --rpcapi 'eth,web3,personal' --jsonrpc-interface 127.0.0.1 --bootnodes 'enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303,enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303'
```

When I test this node, it's running fine, see the following python shell:

```
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 10:45:20) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from web3 import Web3, KeepAliveRPCProvider, IPCProvider
>>> web3 = Web3(KeepAliveRPCProvider(host='localhost', port='8545'))
>>> web3.eth.blockNumber
1012932
```

However, when I try to unlock my account it returns False (with a proper account hash and password ofcourse)

```
>>> web3.personal.unlockAccount('my-account-hash', 'some-password')
False
```

When I check if it's actually in my list of accounts, I get the following:

```
>>> web3.personal.listAccounts
[]
```

Any ideas would be kindly appreciated.

Comment: The account you want to unlock is not available, list accounts returns an empty array. You can not unlock an account that is not available. See [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/16010/87).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with available? I made the account in parity and I am 100% sure the passphrase is correct.

Comment: `>>> web3.personal.listAccounts` returns `[]`. Can you find out why? Are you using a different datadir or keypath?

Answer (score 2):

The RPC methods under `personal_*` are not exposed by default. The question set it up correctly. (although today, the correct arg is `--jsonrpc-apis 'eth,web3,personal'`).

If you are still failing to connect, and you are using IPC, note that the argument above only sets up calls over HTTP. If you are using IPC, you need to use `--ipc-apis 'eth,web3,personal'` instead.

If you would rather not expose the personal APIs, for security reasons, you can use the [`eth_accounts` RPC call](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_accounts).

```
>>> web3.eth.accounts
['0x...']
```

Comment: How would you use this to unlock an account, rather than just list it?

Comment: Parity does expose it, but my test failed when hitting the endpoint. I updated the answer to include the pitfall I ran into (The personal API is not exposed by default)

Comment: Worked with @blockchaindotsol offline to make sure they are using the right json-rpc-over-http port (rather than the ui port default).

Answer (score -1):

We found the issue, we did not define the key directory properly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi there - can you add a few more specific details about how the directory wasn't defined? (e.g. A typo in the name, or something like that?) It might help others in future. And get more upvotes :-)