# Parity halts on connecting to the private network. RPC io error: Address already in use (os error 98)

Tags: parity

I followed (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/13035/4575) to connect to my private network using `Parity`. Same configuration works on the different node.

`Parity` halts on connection. It won't give any output or log for me to track what went wrong. What should I do to prevent this problem?

```
parity --chain parity.json --network-id 23422 --reserved-peers myPrivateNetwork.txt -ludp=debug,tcp=debug,sync=debug --jsonrpc-port 8546
2017-05-19 12:40:55  main INFO parity::run  Starting Parity/v1.7.0-unstable-7707f75-20170327/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.16.0
2017-05-19 12:40:55  main INFO parity::run  State DB configuration: fast
2017-05-19 12:40:55  main INFO parity::run  Operating mode: active
2017-05-19 12:40:55  main INFO ethcore::service  Configured for Ebloc using Ethash engine
2017-05-19 12:40:55  hyper-client INFO miner  Updated conversion rate to Ξ1 = US$110.54 (1076964100 wei/gas)
...//HALTS do not do anything.
```

It exits with following error message: `RPC io error: Address already in use (os error 98)`. But I have doubled check that the `port 8546` is empty. `netstat -antu | grep "8546"` returns empty.  When I try with `--jsonrpc-port 8547` or different empty port number, it gives the same error message.

Comment: Does that also happen on port 53216? Which version of Parity is that?

Comment: `version Parity/v1.7.0-unstable-7707f75-20170327/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.16.0` and same issue occured when I try with: `--jsonrpc-port 53216` @5chdn

Comment: I build `Parity` from source with: `cargo build --release` @5chdn

Comment: Why are you running nightly by the way?

Comment: `nightly release`? Actually no specific reason. It was the only installation guide I was able to find. Do you suggest any other release I could try? @5chdn

Comment: Well either switch to beta 1.6.7 or recompile your nightly build. The version string suggests you didn't update your client for 7 weeks.

Comment: Could I download the 1.6.7 version from the github and could just do: `cargo build --release`? please note that I am on linux @5chdn

Comment: 1.6.7-beta fixed the problem! @5chdn